# Is it possible to make a grid with 6 cells like this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a grid with 6 cells with no empty cells in between, but couldn't manage to do that ..
I tried to create 9 cells and then span, but it didn't work out as there were empty cells in between.

I appreciate your feedback, I want it to be shaped the same as this picture:

[image: Grid 6 cells no empty cells]

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  /* \/ below is just for styling \/ */
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">4</div>
  <div class="col">5</div>
  <div class="col">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to create 9 cells and then span...

That was the mistake. With a 12 columns grid, it works fine.

How do you divide 9 by 2 (for the second row)? All your cell borders have to fit with a column side... So choose a number that is dividable for each possible cell amount for a row.

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
}
.cell{
  border: 1px solid red;
  display:flex; 
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}
.item-1{
  grid-column: 1 / span 12;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.item-2{
  grid-column: 1 / span 6;
  grid-row: 2;
}
.item-3{
  grid-column: 7 / span 6;
  grid-row: 2;
}
.item-4{
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
  grid-row: 3;
}
.item-5{
  grid-column: 5 / span 4;
  grid-row: 3;
}
.item-6{
  grid-column: 9 / span 4;
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell item-1">1</div>
  <div class="cell item-2">2</div>
  <div class="cell item-3">3</div>
  <div class="cell item-4">4</div>
  <div class="cell item-5">5</div>
  <div class="cell item-6">6</div>
</div>
```